# .htaccess rewrite rule rewrite virtual ".html" file to page with get parameter, not working

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a php site that can load some content with a $_GET[''] parameter:

https://www.example.com --> https://www.example.com?item=0 
in this case item=0 open the homepage with the first image popup opened.

What I want to do is to open https:// www.example.com?item=0 with a virtual ".html" file using .htaccess file.

The result should be like this: 
(one of items is called "freedom")
calling https:// www.example.com/freedom.html should be the same to call https:// www.example.com?item=0, but without showing "?item=0.
I want just to show https:// www.example.com/freedom.html in the address bar.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Activate mod_expires for this directory
ExpiresActive on

# locally cache common image types for 7 days
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 7 days"

# cache CSS files for 24 hours
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 7 days"

# chache JS files for 24 hours
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 7 days"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
# enable the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
# Set your root directory
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^freedom\.html$ /?item=0 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^meet-new-people\.html$ /?item=1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^landscapes\.html$ /?item=2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^wildness\.html$ /?item=3 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^hiking\.html$ /?item=4 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^peaks\.html$ /?item=5 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^paths\.html$ /?item=6 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^getaway\.html$ /?item=7 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^experiment-with\.html$ /?item=8 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^rullini/freedom\.html$ /rullini/?item=0 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^rullini/misterioso-bianco\.html$ /rullini/?item=1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^rullini/the-last-snow\.html$ /rullini/?item=2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^rullini/wildness\.html$ /rullini/?item=3 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^rullini/the-green-mountains\.html$ /rullini/?item=4 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^rullini/hiking\.html$ /rullini/?item=5 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^rullini/sea-of-clouds\.html$ /rullini/?item=6 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I generate this .htaccess file using a php task that read the Images names on database and add the related rule to the file.

P.S: The http to https:// www...... redirecting is made in PHP, not in htaccess.
P.P.S: The website use a redirecting logic that sends the request to the mobile page or to the desktop page in base on the client type:

```
session_start();
$item = -1;
if(isset($_GET['item'])) {
    $item = $_GET['item'];
    if($item<0) $item=0;
}
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
{
    if($item>=0) {
        header('Location: ../mobile.php?item=' . $item);
    } else {
        header('Location: ../mobile.php');
    }
} else {
    if($item>=0) {
        header('Location: ../desktop.php?item=' . $item);
    } else {
        header('Location: ../desktop.php');
    }
}
```

Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the leading ^ is really needed there, it tells that the rule should match the requested url from the very first character.
Update: Leave out R=301 too since it means redirect instead of masking.
Try this:

```
 (.*)/hiking\.html$ $1/?item=3 [L]
```

Comment: I changed as you wrote but still show the parameter:
    RewriteRule (.*)/hiking\.html$ $1/?item=4 [R=301,L]

Comment: Sorry - mistook your initial issue then.
Try to leave the R=301 part out, that makes it a redirect instead of a "masking". See the updated answer.

Comment: Sorry but even in this case it does'nt works! I really don't know why because  In other sies of mine this procedure works!

Comment: What happens with the last one?

Comment: I was asking for the result it gives, the error or something.
Try: hiking\.html$ ?item=3 [L] then.

Comment: Good morning, unfortunately with `hiking\.html$ ?item=3 [L]`, calling https://www.eliusoutdoor.com/hiking.html it change to https://www.eliusoutdoor.com/desktop.php?item=4 ...
I really don't know how but I know that it's possible.

Comment: Well, that part is due to the php redirects, when the .htaccess finishes its work. Just to give a hint:
eliusoutdoor.com/index.php?page=hiking masking address as eliusoutdoor.com/hiking
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #no such file exists`
`RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]`

then in a single index.php file your serve the contents for both the mobile and the desktop layouts like:
`if (userAgentCheck() == "mobile")
displayMobileLayout($_POST["page"])`
`else
displayDesktopLayout($_POST["page"]´

Comment: Ok! I have to remove the home page redirecting system, true?

Comment: Yes, I'd suggest you to turn it into a junction from where all your page can be displayed using the same php file, most of the php frameworks use this logic in their main controller, one file gets the request does the necessary work to find the content of that page, show it to the user if it exists, if not - then you can redirect to a 404 if you want.